# Fastest method to read an array into a string

Tags: c, arrays

I have a *p as representing the array below is how I am reading it now. What I need the fastest method to read it and strore into a string variable in C. Any recommendation please?

```
char *hexValue="";
while(p) {
    printf("\n\nstr: %s\n", p);
    asprintf(&hexValue,"%s%02x",hexValue,p);
    p++;
}
```

Below is the whole function codes.

```
void dummyProcesssPacket(const struct pfring_pkthdr *h, 
             const u_char *p, const u_char *user_bytes) {
  long threadId = (long)user_bytes;
  printf("\nIN Dummy\n");
  numPkts[threadId]++, numBytes[threadId] += h->len+24 /* 8 Preamble + 4 CRC + 12 IFG */;

#ifdef ENABLE_BPF
  if (userspace_bpf && bpf_filter(filter.bf_insns, p, h->caplen, h->len) == 0)
    return; /* rejected */

  numPktsFiltered[threadId]++;
#endif

  if(touch_payload) {
    volatile int __attribute__ ((unused)) i;

    i = p[12] + p[13];
  }

  if(verbose) {
    printf("\nverbose :");
    struct ether_header *ehdr;
    char buf1[32], buf2[32];
    struct ip *ip;
    int s;
    uint usec;
    uint nsec=0;


    int i=0;
    int j=0,line=0,packSize=h->caplen;
    char *hexValue="";
    while(j<packSize/16)
    {
      printf("%06x: ",line++);
        for(i=0;i<16;i++)
        {
          printf("%02x ",p[j*16+i]);
          asprintf(&hexValue,"%s%02x",hexValue,p[j*16+i]);
        }
        printf("   |");
        /*for(i=0;i<16;i++)
        {
           if(isprint(p[j*16+i]))
             printf("%c",p[j*16+i]);
           else
             printf(".");
        }*/
        printf("|\n");
        j++;
    }
    printf("\nTotal hex value is %s",hexValue);




    if(h->ts.tv_sec == 0) {
      memset((void*)&h->extended_hdr.parsed_pkt, 0, sizeof(struct pkt_parsing_info));
      pfring_parse_pkt((u_char*)p, (struct pfring_pkthdr*)h, 5, 1, 1);
    }

    s = (h->ts.tv_sec + thiszone) % 86400;

    if(h->extended_hdr.timestamp_ns) {
      if (pd->dna.dna_dev.mem_info.device_model != intel_igb_82580 /* other than intel_igb_82580 */)
        s = ((h->extended_hdr.timestamp_ns / 1000000000) + thiszone) % 86400;
      /* "else" intel_igb_82580 has 40 bit ts, using gettimeofday seconds:
       * be careful with drifts mixing sys time and hw timestamp */
      usec = (h->extended_hdr.timestamp_ns / 1000) % 1000000;
      nsec = h->extended_hdr.timestamp_ns % 1000;
    } else {
      usec = h->ts.tv_usec;
    }

    printf("%02d:%02d:%02d.%06u%03u ",
       s / 3600, (s % 3600) / 60, s % 60,
       usec, nsec);

    ehdr = (struct ether_header *) p;
    printf("\n\nBefore Extexted :%d",use_extended_pkt_header);
    if(use_extended_pkt_header) {
      printf("\nafter USE EXE");
      printf("%s[if_index=%d]",
        h->extended_hdr.rx_direction ? "[RX]" : "[TX]",
        h->extended_hdr.if_index);

      printf("[%s -> %s] ",
         etheraddr_string(h->extended_hdr.parsed_pkt.smac, buf1),
         etheraddr_string(h->extended_hdr.parsed_pkt.dmac, buf2));    

      if(h->extended_hdr.parsed_pkt.offset.vlan_offset)
    printf("[vlan %u] ", h->extended_hdr.parsed_pkt.vlan_id);

      if (h->extended_hdr.parsed_pkt.eth_type == 0x0800 /* IPv4*/ || h->extended_hdr.parsed_pkt.eth_type == 0x86DD /* IPv6*/) {

        if(h->extended_hdr.parsed_pkt.eth_type == 0x0800 /* IPv4*/ ) {
      printf("[IPv4][%s:%d ", intoa(h->extended_hdr.parsed_pkt.ipv4_src), h->extended_hdr.parsed_pkt.l4_src_port);
      printf("-> %s:%d] ", intoa(h->extended_hdr.parsed_pkt.ipv4_dst), h->extended_hdr.parsed_pkt.l4_dst_port);




                    char sql_lite[1500];
                    int lastID = mysql_insert_id(conn);
                    printf("\n\n\nLAT IS %d",lastID);
                    char *hexValue="";
                    while(p) {
                  printf("\n\nstr: %s\n", p);
                  asprintf(&hexValue,"%s%02x",hexValue,p);
                  p++;
               }
                    //printf("\n\n char size : p size %lu ",sizeof(p));
                    sprintf(sql_lite, "insert into tblPL1 values ('%d','%s','%s')",'2013-05-11 20:20:20',p[0]);
              puts(sql_lite);
              //error = sqlite3_exec(conn, sql_lite, 0, 0, 0);




        } else {
          printf("[IPv6][%s:%d ",    in6toa(h->extended_hdr.parsed_pkt.ipv6_src), h->extended_hdr.parsed_pkt.l4_src_port);
          printf("-> %s:%d] ", in6toa(h->extended_hdr.parsed_pkt.ipv6_dst), h->extended_hdr.parsed_pkt.l4_dst_port);
        }

    printf("[l3_proto=%s]", proto2str(h->extended_hdr.parsed_pkt.l3_proto));

    if(h->extended_hdr.parsed_pkt.tunnel.tunnel_id != NO_TUNNEL_ID) {
      printf("[TEID=0x%08X][tunneled_proto=%s]", 
         h->extended_hdr.parsed_pkt.tunnel.tunnel_id,
         proto2str(h->extended_hdr.parsed_pkt.tunnel.tunneled_proto));

      if(h->extended_hdr.parsed_pkt.eth_type == 0x0800 /* IPv4*/ ) {
        printf("[IPv4][%s:%d ",
           intoa(h->extended_hdr.parsed_pkt.tunnel.tunneled_ip_src.v4),
           h->extended_hdr.parsed_pkt.tunnel.tunneled_l4_src_port);
        printf("-> %s:%d] ", 
           intoa(h->extended_hdr.parsed_pkt.tunnel.tunneled_ip_dst.v4),
           h->extended_hdr.parsed_pkt.tunnel.tunneled_l4_dst_port);
      } else {
        printf("[IPv6][%s:%d ", 
           in6toa(h->extended_hdr.parsed_pkt.tunnel.tunneled_ip_src.v6),
           h->extended_hdr.parsed_pkt.tunnel.tunneled_l4_src_port);
        printf("-> %s:%d] ",
           in6toa(h->extended_hdr.parsed_pkt.tunnel.tunneled_ip_dst.v6),
           h->extended_hdr.parsed_pkt.tunnel.tunneled_l4_dst_port);
      }   
    }

    printf("[hash=%u][tos=%d][tcp_seq_num=%u]",
      h->extended_hdr.pkt_hash,
          h->extended_hdr.parsed_pkt.ipv4_tos, 
      h->extended_hdr.parsed_pkt.tcp.seq_num);

      } else {
    if(h->extended_hdr.parsed_pkt.eth_type == 0x0806 /* ARP */)
      printf("[ARP]");
    else
      printf("[eth_type=0x%04X]", h->extended_hdr.parsed_pkt.eth_type);
      }

      printf(" [caplen=%d][len=%d][parsed_header_len=%d][eth_offset=%d][l3_offset=%d][l4_offset=%d][payload_offset=%d]\n",
        h->caplen, h->len, h->extended_hdr.parsed_header_len,
        h->extended_hdr.parsed_pkt.offset.eth_offset,
        h->extended_hdr.parsed_pkt.offset.l3_offset,
        h->extended_hdr.parsed_pkt.offset.l4_offset,
        h->extended_hdr.parsed_pkt.offset.payload_offset);

    } else {
      printf("[%s -> %s][eth_type=0x%04X][caplen=%d][len=%d] (use -m for details)\n",
         etheraddr_string(ehdr->ether_shost, buf1),
         etheraddr_string(ehdr->ether_dhost, buf2), 
         ntohs(ehdr->ether_type),
         h->caplen, h->len);
    }
  }

  if(verbose == 2) {
      int i;

      for(i = 0; i < h->caplen; i++)
        printf("%02X ", p[i]);
      printf("\n");
  }

  if(unlikely(add_drop_rule)) {
    if(h->ts.tv_sec == 0)
      pfring_parse_pkt((u_char*)p, (struct pfring_pkthdr*)h, 4, 0, 1);

    drop_packet_rule(h);
  }
}
```

Comment: what is the declaration of p ? is it `char *p`?

Comment: if it's const so you can not change it with p++. you should get an error in the compilation

Comment: please share the whole code

Comment: I have added the whole code.

Comment: @MOHAMED it was `const u_char *p` and not `u_char *const p`...

Answer (score 1):

1) For

```
while(p) {
```

should be

```
while(*p) {
```

2) For

```
asprintf(&hexValue,"%s%02x",hexValue,p);
```

I m not sure if passing `hexValue` twice in the input arguments is supported by asprinf, but I recommend to use another variable to be confident that tere is no surprise to  happen:

3) You can change

```
char *hexValue="";
while(p) {
    printf("\n\nstr: %s\n", p);
    asprintf(&hexValue,"%s%02x",hexValue,p);
    p++;
}
```

by

```
char *hexValue=malloc(((h->caplen)*2)+1);
char *q=hexValue;
int i;
for (i=0;i<h->caplen;q+=2,i++)
       sprintf(q,"%02X",*(p+i));
printf("%s\n", hexValue);
```

**Explaination:**
The charachter code is presented in 2 hexadecimal numbers. As you did in the asprintf format specifier `"%02X"`. So for every element in your p you need 2 char to write in the hex code of each p element. so that's why the length of hexValue = 2 * length of p. And I added 1 because this is will be use for the null terminator charachter.

Concerning

```
for (;*p;q+=2,p++)
    sprintf(q,"%02X",*p);
```

`q` initially is pointed to `hexadecimal` and for each `for` iteration q is incremented with 2 `q+=2` because you have to write your code in 2 characheters.

**EDIT** according the segfault
I tried to run the code in a small program an it work. try the following code in a separate program and see if there is a segfault

```
int main()

{

    const unsigned char pp[] = {'a','b','c','d'};
    const unsigned char *p = pp;
    int caplen = 4;
    char *hexValue=malloc(((caplen)*2)+1);
    char *q=hexValue;
    int i;
    for (i=0;i<caplen;q+=2,i++)
           sprintf(q,"%02X",*(p+i));
    printf("%s\n", hexValue);

}
```

Comment: @Mohamaded so what modification you recommend?

Comment: @I need to transform those hex value into readable value and into one single string all the payload details of the packet

Comment: ok first line is you allocatin memory why *2 cause its char but char i just one byte rite? This line I am not too sure for (;*p;q+=2,p++)
       sprintf(q,"%02X",*p);

Comment: @I think p should represent the largest possible packet size then

Comment: @Sorry it gives me segementation fault

Comment: @MOHAMED 4) is wrong. `const` is fine there. The thing the pointer points to is const, not the pointer itself. Although the const is being casted away in other places, which is a bad idea.

Comment: @new14 what is the size of char array of p? is it the same h->len ?

Comment: @Oktalist I am kind of confuse when you say is fine then this "const is being casted away in other places, which is a bad idea"

Comment: @p should be minimum this h->caplen

Comment: @new14 When you write `(u_char*)p` or `(struct ether_header *) p` you are casting `p` from a pointer-to-const to a pointer-to-non-const, which could allow you to modify the thing that it points to, leading to undefined behaviour.

Comment: @I tried char *hexValue=malloc(((h->caplen)*2)+1); also after sometime I get segementation fault.

Comment: @new14 I updated the answer. now should works. I considered in the solution that the length of p is h->caplen

Comment: @All what modification can be done to my existing codes as it works just that I want to speed it up ?

Comment: @Mohamed how about it not using h->caplen just using the p can we work it out just incase the h->caplen did not tally well ?

Comment: the solution I give you is the fastet one using sprintf and is fasted comparing to the solution asprintf

Comment: If you want to make more faster you  have to avoid using sprintf and develop your own function which convert your code to hexadecimal char codes

Comment: @new14 are you sure that the segfault is from the code I suggested? if the case please check that the length of p is really h->caplen

Comment: @How about your final codes can we adjust it to avoid segmentation fault?

Comment: @Yes I am sure because the rest of the codes have been working well.

Comment: @MOHAMED it run but I get this warning 
test2.c: In function âmainâ:
test2.c:10: warning: incompatible implicit declaration of built-in function âmallocâ

Comment: @MOHAMED I was thinking remain my old codes just that this part asprintf(&hexValue,"%s%02x",hexValue,p); I want to keep concated the hexValue into a string. How run that ?